# Help with the Palais Smale condition for this functional

Tags: partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, nonlinear-analysis

Consider the functional
$$ I(u)=\frac{1}{2} \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2\ dx + \frac{1}{4} \int_\Omega (1-|u|^2)^2 \ dx - \frac{c}{2} \int_\Omega \langle i\partial_1 u , u\rangle ,$$
where $u:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$ is a $H^1$-function ($H^1=$ Sobolev space), $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ bounded, $c\in (0,\sqrt{2})$ and $\langle , \rangle$ stands for the scalar product of $\mathbb{C} \equiv \mathbb{R}^2$. I have proved that $I$ is coercive and weakly lower semicontinuous and $C^1$.

I wonder if $I$ **satisfies the Palais Smale condition at level $c$ $(PS)_c$**, that is, assume that $x_n$ is a sequence s.t $I(x_n)\to c$ and $I ' (x_n)\to 0$, then there exists a converging subsequence of $x_n$ in $H^1(\Omega)$.

Any idea is welcome. Thank you in advance!.

Comment: What did you tried?

Comment: if $I(x_n)\to c$, then $x_n$ is bouneded, then it has a weak limit $x_*$... but I am stuck. Obviously, in finite dimension the PS condition is trivial (via Bolzano-Weierstrass). But sincerelly I have no idea how to show PS condition  here.